# SSRS Subreport won't run

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS subreport that is passed a variety of parameters from the parent report.  Some of these parameters are visible in the subreport's parameter list and some are hidden.  There are also two additional data parameters are not passed from the parent. These need to be manually selected to actually run the subreport.
The issue is this: when I pass info into the report by clicking on the hyperlink in the parent report, the report will not run inside BIDS.  Instead the parameter portion of the report appears to refresh.  If I click the View Report button again, it will do the same thing.
The parent and subreport work fine though on the Report Server.
Also, if I use the subreport by itself in BIDS or the Report Server, the subreport will run just fine.
I'm at a bit of a loss to understand what is happening here.  Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A few things to check... `1.`  Check the defalts values for the parameter on both the development and the deployed version - once deployed, any changes to parameter defaults are not updated on the deployed version unless the deployed report is delete and redeployed. `2.` delete the rdldata file from your project folder as it may be using cached data in your development version

Comment: There were default values listed.  Without them I cannot run the subreport by itself.  I think the default values are overwritten by the calling report, but it's hard to say.  I tried suggestion 2 of deleitng the rdldata file, but it didn't work.  It was a good idea, but the issue is still happening.

Comment: the default values will only be overridden if the they are passed from the parent report, if they are not passed, the defaults are used. Did you compare defaults in your development version vs the deployed version? were they identical?

Comment: I compared defaults in both environments and they were identical.